# Twitter access token usage

Tags: api, rest, twitter

I want to access twitter API on behalf of user.

I'm a bit confused with Twitter access token usage. As I compare to Github API which is very easy to integrate with, I have `accessToken` which is simply put as query parameter `access_token` to every HTTP request.

With github I have access token (from test application), but I woundering where should it actually go - query string, headers?

Would be happy if someone clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It should go in the `Authorization` header, with the word "Bearer " (and a space) before it.

e.g. in Android / Java `HttpGet` call:

```
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
```